# Ubuntu 15.10 on VM can't boot up after update

Tags: boot, 15.10, vmware-player

I am working on a VM 12 Player and Ubuntu 15.10（updated from 15.04), and I receive an software update notice several days ago and updated it. It tells me to restart the computer but I just keep working and decide to restart later. Finally when I restart it today, it can't boot...
It starts normally and everything is [OK],and show several seconds on this screen(the time is not long enough for me to type in the user name and password)
[login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKIuQ.png)

and stuck at this screen finally and the '_' is not flashing.
[stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iMCd.png)

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the exact same issue - I managed to get the VM to run by booting it with an older kernel.

To do this, hold down the shift key while booting, the Grub menu will then be displayed. You now have the option to boot from an older kernel.